# Scan And Fix a RAW drive

Tags: windows-7, android, htc-hero

Basically I got the same problem as described in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/33986/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-scan-and-fix-message-when-inserting-an-sd-card). When I plug my HTC Hero Android Phone with USB into my Windows 7 computer I get a "Do you want to Scan and Fix" message. However, if I click "Scan and Fix", the USB instantly unplugs itself, so that's no good.

I've tried updating drivers from HTC with no luck. I've also tried running chkdisk from command-line with the message that it can't be used in RAW drives. This is really really annoying, and the SD card works just fine if I ignore the message, so I just want a way to disable/hide this message permanently.

If anyone have some ideas how this can be done, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the SD card out of your phone, put the SD card in an SD card adapter and checkdisk it from there. It's possible that by using your phone as an adapter, it prevents you from checking it properly.

Comment: My phone got updated to Android 2.1 today, and then I could Format the SD card from the phone itself, which fixed the issue. This means your answer is also correct, since it would effectively do the same thing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on the sd card inside my blackberry. They way I fixed it was I clicked the x on the message that pops up (the one that says scan/fix). Then I 'safely removed' the drive. When I reconnected the phone it didn't error and loaded up fine.

Comment: Had absolutly zero effect on the problem :(