# How to stop "Do you want to scan and fix drive" message in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb-flash-drive

I use my USB flash (thumb) drive quite often to move data between several computers (Macs and PCs.) When I plug in this flash drive into Windows 7 it shows this message:

> "Do you want to scan and fix ...?"

[image]

If I click "Scan and fix" the message goes away for a little while only to come back again.

Is there a setting in Windows to make this message go away because it is very annoying to click through this window every time I plug in my drive?

PS. I run this same flash drive on a Mac computer and it never tells me that there's an issue with the drive.

PS2. I have other flash drives that keep showing this same message on Windows 7. They all cannot have the same issue, can they :)

Comment: Does it still happen? What were you using the flash-drives for? It’s possible that some program had open handles to files on the flash-drive.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/33986/327413

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this solution [on the net](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/75650-disable-scan-fix-removable-drive-notification.html):

1. goto Start
2. type msconfig
3. select Services Tab
4. Scroll down and Uncheck Shell Hardware Detection
5. Restart Windows

Comment: +1 for the correct answer, though people wanting to do this should be made aware that it will also disable AutoPlay functionality, i.e. only use this if you're happy to lose that.

Comment: this didn't work for me. The service is stopped (as I also checked in services.msc) but the message keeps popping out

Answer (score 2):

Question: How do you remove a USB flash drive from your system?  Do you properly unmount it?  In windows, this would be do you select the tray icon to gracefully allow you to remove your device.....or do you just yank it out?

If you are yanking it out without properly disconnecting (which flushes any important data out of the system and onto the USB drive, and sets the "clean" bit if you will)....programs are most likely responding to this action.

I'd suggest that for long life and no surprises that you first properly disconnect the system from accessing the USB drive before removal.

The message is detecting previous improper removal, and I'd scan and fix it!

Comment: Agreed. The fix is not to yank out the USB pen drive. Use the 'safe removal' mothod then unplug it.

Comment: I disconnect them through an icon next to the clock on Windows 7. On earlier versions of Windows it is too complicated to do the same, so yes, I do yank them out there. Note that I've been doing this for as long as I remember and it never caused an issue with data or the life span of the USB drive. And, don't blame me for the inability of the OS to provide decent USB removal controls. They issued "a million" updates to that Windows and none addressed this! So the bottom line, you're saying that there's no way to get rid of that message on Windows 7, is there?

Comment: All I can say is its your USB stick......

Comment: Actually, if the volume is set to *Quick Removal*, then Windows does not cache writes, so you *shouldn’t* need to eject because writes are done immediately. Removable drives are set to *Quick Removal* by default, which is why ahmd1 has been able to do “just yank it out” for years without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-disable-the-chkdsk-check-disk-on-start-up/35f58c69-7a6c-4e1b-aec3-26d7131ec643) solution to disable checking disk on a specified letter.

```
regedit
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
autocheck autochk /k:C /k:D *
```

Comment: This looks like it's exactly what I want, but it doesn't seem to work.